# How to find the Character at a specific index within a given cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was wondering if there is a function in Excel that will return a character at a given index of a single cell.

For example, I have a cell that says HELLO. I am looking for a function (or combo of functions) that will allow to me to bring back whatever character is located at index 2, which is, unless the index of an Excel Cell starts at 1 and not 0, L.

I am essentially looking for an Excel function that is similar to the charAt() method in Java.

Also, I know that I could use a =left function to return all the characters up to a specific point in a cell, but I just want one specific character at one specific point returned per cell.

Please let me know if you need me to elaborate anymore.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As follow up from comments, this one works:

```
=MID(A1,2,1)
```